# Processing - How to move a piece using mouse?

Tags: java

Let us say i have an ellipse, how to put it to the location where mouse is released?

Can anyone give me it's implementation for a knight ?

let us say i have an existing circle at :

```java
float x = 10;
float y = 10;
ellipse(x,y,50,50);
```

how do i use the mouse to change it's location. let us say it is a pawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty unclear what you're asking, but you can just use the `mouseX` and `mouseY` variables along with the `mouseReleased()` function:

```java
float circleX;
float circleY;

void draw(){
   background(0);
   ellipse(circleX, circlY, 10, 10);
}

void mouseReleased(){
   circleX = mouseX;
   circleY = mouseY;
}
```

If this doesn't answer your question, then please put together an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing exactly what you've tried and where you're stuck. Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's designed more for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions.